# Does NumPy have an optimization for preventing unnecessary copies when an array is copied onto itself?

Tags: numpy

Copying data from one memory location to another takes time:

```
v = np.random.rand(10, 128, 128)
w = np.random.rand(128, 128)
np.may_share_memory(v,w)  # Output: False
%timeit v[2] = w  # 4.65 us
```

So it's intriguing to see that NumPy appears to have some means of quitting early when the copy was unnecessary:

```
w = v[2]
np.may_share_memory(v[2], w)   # Output: False
%timeit v[2] = w   # 146 ns
```

And this quit seems to be even faster than the quick bounds check done by may_share_memory:

```
%timeit np.may_share_memory(v[2], w)   # 525 ns
```

What's going on here? In my current project, I have many arrays initially sliced from a much larger array. By the time I've finished working on the slices, the shared memory relationship between the slice and the parent most likely hasn't been violated, but maybe it has been and I need to copy the modified slice back to its parent.

If NumPy optimizes away the unnecessary copy, as it looks like it might, it would be a no-brainer for my code to always do the assignment back to the parent rather than try to determine on its own whether the shared memory relationship has been broken, making the copyback necessary.

Comment: You need to read on [copies and views](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html). Whether or not you have a view depends on the way you sliced/indexed your smaller array.

Comment: In the second case `w` is a `view` of `v`.  It's a new array, but its data-buffer is a portion of `v's`.  Any in place change to `w` are automatically reflected in `v`.  So in the  timed assignment, it doesn't need to copy anything.  `w.base` is `v`.  But if you had also done `w=w+1`, you'd see a copy time.

Comment: There's more to this than `view` and sharing memory.  For example I wouldn't be surprised if `v[3]=w` or `v[::-1] =w` take longer than the first case, since they may require an intermediate buffer.

Comment: @hpaulj Yep. +10% on my machine. Also there are probably caching consideration. For example `x=w.T` cost the same as `x=w` (that is, practically nothing). Even we your `*1`, `x=w.T*1` and `x=w*1` cost almost the same (that is, this time, not nothing, since it is copied). Because `x` is created with reverted strides, even tho a copy occurs. And iteration when copying is done in memory order. While `v[2]=w`  cost 3 times less thjat `v[2]=w.T`. Same amount of copied data. But this time, iteration cannot me done in memory order (one of `v[2]` and `w` has to be iterated in the "wrong order").

Comment: And that is not nothing (3 times more expansive, considering that there is no other optimisation explanaton It is the exact same 16384 numbers copied. In both case a `for(int y=0; y<128; y++) for(x=0; x<128; x++) v[2][stridev1*y+stridev2*x]=w[stridew1*y+stridew2*x]`. But if it is stridev2 that is small, and stridew1 (or the otherway), then, it has the same effect as swapping, for one of the arrays, the `for x` and `for y` loops. And in HPC, you learn to avoid by all cost iterating 2D arrays with the wrong order for the nested for loops.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy would not copy memory if it were the same. But that is not what you are experiencing here.

Just try

```
v = np.random.rand(10, 128, 128)
w = np.random.rand(128, 128)
w = v[2]
```

And you'll see that `w=v[2]` is very fast also. When v and w have nothing at all in common.

That is because, as hpaulj explained in comment, `w=v[2]` is not a code that copies anything, whatever the context. Firstly, it has nothing to do with whatever was in w before. Whatever was is w is forgotten (that is not numpy's consideration here, but python: you create a new variable `w` and the old one is fogotten. It is exactly as if you wrote `w="hello"; w=v[2]`.

Secondly, `v[2]` is a view of v, not a copy. So what you are doing here, is creating a new variable `w` (unrelated to the former one), that will hold a view of v.

In other words, it is not `w=v[2]` that is fast, it is `v[2]` itself that is. To use hpaulj's example, compare

```
timeit.timeit(lambda:v[2])
```

and

```
timeit.timeit(lambda:v[2]*1)
```

Nothig to do with `w`. First one just have to return a structure pointing to the same memory used by `v` with a few metadata tweaks. The second has to create a new memory area, and copy data to this memory.

If you want to do your experiment right, and verify if numpy has mechanism to avoid unnecessary copy (which it does. Just, your experiment shows nothing about it), you should do it that way, using commands like `w[:]=v[2]` (which this times doesn't mean "just extract a view of v, and store it in a new variable `w`, forgetting whatever existing previous variable w if there was one"; but means "fill numbers of w with numbers taken from v[2]"):

```
v = np.random.rand(10, 128, 128)
w = np.random.rand(128, 128)

# This line is optional. It changes nothing to the experiment
# But you may try with and without it to check that there
# is no mechanism to avoid copy when it is the same content
v[2]=w # v[2] and w contain the same data, but not at the same memory

# This does copy what is in v[2] in w (already allocated) w memory
%timeit w[:]=v[2] # copy the contents of v[2] in w data.
# See that this times it is not fast at all
# 10 μs on my computer, 4,65 on yours probably

w=v[2] # No need to measure time, it is not a copy. It is just preparation
       # for next experiment. 

# Now again:
%timeit w[:]=v[2] 
# this times it is fast. 
# 680 ns on my computer. 
# And this times, it proves something. The exact same 
# command w[:]=v[2] is faster the 2nd time than the 1st.
# It is because what
# you were trying to see: because we ask numpy to copy the content of v[2]
# as the new content of w, but numpy detects that this is the same thing, 
# (not just the same content ; but the same memory address) so 
# does nothing. As if you wrote "v[2]=v[2]"
```

So second experiment is fast, not because `v[2]` is a view. That instruction `w[:]=v[2]` is about copying data, not creating a view. So it should be slow. As slow as the underlying `for(int i=0; i<128; i++) for(int j=0; j<128; j++) memory_w[stridew1*i+stridew2*j] = memory_v[stridev1*2+strivev2*i+stridev3*j];` that occurs under the hood. And yet it is fast. Because, indeed, numpy won't copy memory onto itself.